# Why doesn't md-menu align with md-button when ng-href is added to the button?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Demo here: http://codepen.io/audiodude/pen/vLyNvw

The only difference between the top and the bottom is that the top uses an `md-button` with an `ng-href` attribute, which gets compiled by Angular Material to an `a` tag, while the bottom uses a plain `md-button` that gets compiled to a `button` tag. However, the `.md-button` class does seem to add all of the same styling to the anchor version of the button.

So why does the menu in the top example get seemingly pushed to a new line?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="buttondemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout="column" layout-align="start center">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center" layout-fill>
      <md-card flex-sm="95" flex-gt-md="70" layout="column">
        <div layout-sm="column" layout-gt-sm="row" flex>
          <div flex layout>
            <md-button ng-href="https://www.google.com" class="md-primary">
              <md-icon aria-label="launch">launch</md-icon> Link
            </md-button>
            <md-menu>
              <md-button aria-label="Open edit menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
                <md-icon md-menu-origin>arrow_drop_down</md-icon>
              </md-button>
              <md-menu-content width="5">
                <md-button>Menu Choice</md-button>
              </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
          </div>
          <span flex></span>
        </div>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </md-content>

  <md-content layout="column" layout-align="start center">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center" layout-fill>
      <md-card flex-sm="95" flex-gt-md="70" layout="column">
        <div layout-sm="column" layout-gt-sm="row" flex>
          <div flex>
            <md-button class="md-primary">
              <md-icon aria-label="launch">launch</md-icon> Link
            </md-button>
            <md-menu>
              <md-button aria-label="Open edit menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
                <md-icon md-menu-origin>arrow_drop_down</md-icon>
              </md-button>
              <md-menu-content width="5">
                <md-button>Menu Choice</md-button>
              </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
          </div>
          <span flex></span>
        </div>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

You just forgot to add "layout" attribute (by default it's row) in line 6.

Comment: Adding the `layout` attribute certainly helps, but the menu icon is still misaligned with the button on the top example: http://codepen.io/audiodude/pen/dGOMNv

But...that looks like an existing issue: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4943